# how to select column iteratively in spark

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

If I have dataframe with 100s columns. How do I select iteratevly below columns.

One final dataframe output from below code may be:

```
|a      | id    | year|m2000 | m2001 | m2002 | .... | m2015|
|"hello"| 1    | 2001  | 0    | 0     | 0   | ... |   0  |
|"hello"| 1   | 2015  | 0    | 0     | 0   | ... |   0  |
|"hello"| 2   | 2002  | 0    | 0     | 0   | ... |   0  |
|"hello"| 2   | 2015  | 0    | 0     | 0   | ... |   0  |
```

but another dataframe may have more years so it will be like the below example

```
|a      | id    | year|m2000 | m2001 | m2002 | .... | m2019|
|"hello"| 1    | 2001  | 0    | 0     | 0   | ... |   0  |
|"hello"| 1   | 2015  | 0    | 0     | 0   | ... |   0  |
|"hello"| 2   | 2002  | 0    | 0     | 0   | ... |   0  |
|"hello"| 2   | 2015  | 0    | 0     | 0   | ... |   0  |
```

I can not use drop as I would have drop 100s cols so select is better in this use case.

I have tried the below but say in this example the range is changeable.

```
a=2000
b=2015
for i in range(a, b + 1):
    df = df.withColumn("M" + str(i), lit(0))
    df = df.select("M" + str(i),"a","id","year")


df.show()
```

but it only shows the first year m2000

```
 a      | id    | year|m2000 | 
|"hello"| 1    | 2001  | 0  |  
|"hello"| 1   | 2015  | 0   | 
|"hello"| 2   | 2002  | 0   | 
|"hello"| 2   | 2015  | 0  |
```

where I want it to show

```
|a      | id    | year|m2000 | m2001 | m2002 | .... | m2015|
|"hello"| 1    | 2001  | 0    | 0     | 0   | ... |   0  |
|"hello"| 1   | 2015  | 0    | 0     | 0   | ... |   0  |
|"hello"| 2   | 2002  | 0    | 0     | 0   | ... |   0  |
|"hello"| 2   | 2015  | 0    | 0     | 0   | ... |   0  |
```

Comment: pass the list of columns in `select`

Comment: (1) Do you want to select all columns with "m{year}", or just 2000 till 2015. And (2) can you assert these columns are always present, or would it be possible sometimes a column is missing (for example like "m2039").

Comment: Interesting question by @remi. I have tried to cater for all scenarios based on your limited information in my answer below. Let me know if there are variations and I will assist

Comment: It will always be a range as such but interesting point if year is missing what occurs. @wwnde answer was great, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not quite clear on what columns you need.  If you want to select everything starting with `m` plus `a`, `id`, `year`, [colRegex](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.colRegex.html) may be helpful.

```
df.select('a','id','year', df.colRegex("`^m200+.+`")).show()
```

If you want to selectively select columns between 2000 and 2015 use list comprehension with the walrus operator as follows

```
df.select('a','id','year', *[c for x in range(2000,2015) if (c:='m'+str(x))in (df.columns)]).show()
```

Please remember 2000 and 2015 can also be declared as variables and passed as follows

```
a=2000
 b=2015
df.select('a','id','year', *[c for x in range(a,b) if (c:='m'+str(x))in (df.columns)]).show()
```

Comment: I didn’t know about the ‘colRegex’ function. Pretty cool feature of PySpark! And I think this exactly what @lunbox is looking for.